# set label_both as default in facet_grid for theme in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I like the label_both feature in facet_grid, but I´d prefer to set it as default. Is this possible somehow - either as default for ggplot or in the specific theme?

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=disp,y=mpg))+geom_point()+facet_grid(cyl~am,labeller = label_both)
```

ggplot v 3.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own function specifying the default.

```
library(ggplot2)

facet_grid_custom <- function(formula, ...) {
  facet_grid(formula,labeller = label_both, ...) 
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp,y=mpg))+ geom_point() + facet_grid_custom(cyl~am)
```

[image]